# Magneto tail effect on the other planet in a binary planet system

Tags: magnetic-field, planetary-science, terrestrial-planets, planetary-atmosphere

Let's say there are 2 earth sized planets orbiting each other around 750,000km apart and at a distance of roughly 1.2 AU from a sunlike star with a mass of 1.105 solar masses. Since they are binary, they would most likely be on the stellar plane and therefore should eclipse eachother regularly. 
Both planets have their own rotation and their own magnetosphere similar to Earth's. 
As one planet orbits in between the second planet and the star, the Magneto tail would pass over the second planet.

**Question: What would this do to the other planet?**

Would the second planet handle this the same as it would the regular stellar wind? Would it blow concentrated radiation at the second world ?

Comment: [The Moon and the Magnetotail](https://www.nasa.gov/topics/moonmars/features/magnetotail_080416.html)

Comment: Great article, so there is an effect that would happen on the second planet. Now would that planets own magnetosphere catch that and deal with it like a heavy dose of solar wind or like a CME? Or at the very least, would it make a great Aurora for those on the planet.

Comment: I expect that the magnetospheres of the 2 planets would form some kind of dynamic combined structure. I can't find any relevant articles online, but there is stuff about the far more intense combined magnetic fields of binary pulsars.